# Ошибка при определении категории для канала guild.create_text_channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я пытаюсь создать канал в определенной категории при запуске бота.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(880008097370865706)
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'⛏-miner-1', category='880024994841768018')
```

Но при запуске бота я получаю ошибку, как я понял связанную с категорией для канала:

```
    parent_id = category.id if category else None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

ID категории указан верно. Без определения категории канал создается рядом с ними. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать имя категории, а не ID.

```
async def __create_text_channel(ctx, *, name: str, category: str): 
   guild = ctx.guild 
   category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=category) 
   print(f'Creating a new text channel: {name}, {category}, {position}') 
   await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name, category=category, 
   position=position) print(f'{name} was been created')
```

Спасибо за подсказку,только вчера начал пользоваться этим сайтом, еще не разобрался.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не помогло.

Comment: а что именно у вас не получилось? Найти имя? Или все равно создает не там?

Comment: При запуске выводится та же ошибка `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.

Comment: а вам действительно нужен ID? И что такое category? Где вы его взяли? Как получили? Судя по ошибке, это просто строка.

Comment: Я составил команду по документации: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel

Comment: я не нашел в документации ничего про ID
вот моя реализация команды:
```
async def __create_text_channel(ctx, *, name: str, category: str):
    guild = ctx.guild
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=category)
    print(f'Creating a new text channel: {name}, {category}, {position}')
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name, category=category, position=position)
    print(f'{name} was been created')
```

Comment: @Daniel если нужно добавить код, добавьте его в сам ответ (нажмите "править" под ответом, чтобы его отредактировать). Комментарии не предназначены для вставки блоков кода.

Comment: Daniel, все получилось, большое спасибо.